# Loading data into Titan with bulbs and then accessing it

Tags: python, titan, gremlin, rexster, bulbs

I am a complete novice in graph databases and all the Titan ecosystem, so please excuse me sounding stupid. I am also suffering from the lack of documentation -_-

I've installed the titan server. I am using Cassandra as a back-end.

I am trying to load basic twitter data into Titan using Python.
I use the ***bulbs*** library for this purpose.
Lets say, i have a list of people i follow on twitter in the **friends** list

my python script goes like this

```
from bulbs.titan import Graph
# some other imports here

# getting the *friends* list for a specified user here


g = Graph()

# a vertex of a specified user
center = g.vertices.create(name = 'sergiikhomenko')


for friend in friends:
    cur_friend = g.vertices.create(name = friend)
    g.edges.create(center,'follows',cur_friend)
```

From what i understand - the above code should have created a graph in Titan with a number of vertices, some of which a connected by the ***follows*** edge.

My questions are:

> How do I save it in Titan?? (like a commit in SQL)
>
> How do I access it later??  Should I be able to access it through
>   gremlin shell?? If yes, how??

My next question would be about visualizing the data, but i am very far from there :)

Please help :) I am completely lost in all this Titan, Gremlin, Rexster,etc. :)

*Update:* One of the requirement of our POC project - is ... python :), that's why i jumped into bulbs straight on. I'll definitely follow the advice below though :)

Comment: Welcome to the club. BTW, if you are planning to use Titan you should know that the Titan development is not full fledged now. You should also consider other alternatives like OrientDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will be somewhat incomplete because I can't really supply answers around Bulbs but you do ask some specific questions which I can try to answer:

> How do I save it in Titan?? (like a commit in SQL)

It's just `g.commit()` in Java/Groovy.

> How do I access it later?? Should I be able to access it through gremlin shell?? If yes, how??

Once it's committed to cassandra, access it with Bulbs, the gremlin shell, some other application, whatever.  Not sure what you're asking really, but I like the Gremlin Console for such things so if have cassandra started locally, start up `bin/gremlin.sh` and do:

```
g = TitanFactory.build()
    .set("storage.backend","cassandra")
    .set("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1")
    .open();
```

That will get you a connection to cassandra and you should be able to query your data.

> I am completely lost in all this Titan, Gremlin, Rexster,etc

My advice to all new users (especially those new to graphs, cassandra, the jvm, etc.) is to slow down.  The fastest way to get discouraged is to try to do python to the bulbs to the rexster to the gremlin over the titan to the cassandra cluster hosted in ec2 with hadoop - and try to load a billion edge graph into that.

If you are new, then start with the latest stuff: TinkerPop3 - http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/ - which bulbs does not yet support - but that's ok because you're learning TinkerPop which is important to learning the whole stack and all of TinkerPop's implementations (e.g. Titan).  Use TinkerGraph (not Titan) with a small subset of your data and make sure you get the pattern for loading that small subset right before you try to go full scale.  Use the Gremlin Console for everything related to this initial goal.  That is a recipe for an easy win.  Under that approach you could likely have a Graph going with some queries over your own data in a day and learn a good portion of what you need to do it with Titan.

Once you have your Graph, get it working in [Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0.M9-incubating/#gremlin-server) (the Rexster replacement for TP3).  Then think about how you might access that via python tooling. Or maybe you figure out how to convert TinkerGraph to Titan (perhaps start with BerkeleyDB rather than cassandra).  My point here is to more slowly increment your involvement with different pieces of the ecosystem because it is otherwise overwhelming.

Comment: Thanks Stephen!! A couple of short questions here.  1.Let's say we have Cassandra that stores the data, and Titan that provides the logical structure for data access, matipulation, etc. (hope i haven't messed up at this point) Can we store multiple separate graphs in Titan (making an analogy to sql schemas here)? Or everything that is stored into Titan (or should i use the name of the underlying database here) is a part of a big whole and cant be broken down to separate graphs in terms of access and manipulation?

Comment: Question 2. What would be your suggestions for accessing saved graph and visualizing it? Even if it would consist of two vertices and one edge :)

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but here is the 3rd question :) Is there any place on the Internet that would provide a two word description for each of the projects (e.g. Titan, Gremlin, Rexster) and how they fit together and which one is good for what? Because each project's description is so complex in terms of vocabulary  and phrasing, that its hard to get a complete picture in ones head.

Comment: you can have one graph per keyspace - see the `storage.cassandra.keyspace` setting.  as for visualization, i'd just use [gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) or [cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/).  note that TinkerPop3 include [gephi integration](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0.M9-incubating/#gephi-plugin). as for terms, i suggest you refocus on TinkerPop3 terminology so I'll point you to the start of the [TP3 docs](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0.M9-incubating/#_tinkerpop3) see the green NOTE box.

Comment: wrt your question edit, i still suggest learning TP3 for your POC.  See the "Community Contributions" section on the [TinkerPop home page](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/) for a set of python libs that might help you there once you get familiar with the stack. fwiw, the developer of Bulbs has told me that he intends to port to TP3 once it reaches GA.

Comment: gremlin shell gives the following error, when i run the code: gremlin> g = TitanFactory.build().set("storage.backend","cassandra").set("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1").open();                                                                No signature of method: static com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.build() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), dump(), equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: If you are using Titan be sure that you are using the Gremlin Console packaged with the Titan distribution.